# Sails set css in specific page

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm using the sails.js framework

I want to know if there is a way for a view to use only one css file, not the other ones being declared in the layout?

That is, ignore the other css definitions and use only one.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Inside of the method that renders your view, return a value that references the stylesheet you want to include.

```
return res.view('someTemplate',{
    myStylesheet: 'link/to/your/stylesheet.css'
})
```

Then, edit your layout.ejs file to include the stylesheet if our new value is present.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
        ...

        <% if(myStylesheet) { %>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= myStylesheet %>">
        <% } %>

        <!--STYLES-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/some/other/stylesheet.css">
        <!--STYLES END--> 
        ...
    ...
...
```

The EJS template pre-processor will now only include the stylesheet you specify if a value is provided.